# Como guardar na base de dado o valor do SelectedItem do DropDownList?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Eu quero registar um cliente e um dos seus atributos é o sexo

Base de dados: o atributo sexo é um nvarchar

ASP.NET: estou trabalhando com uma listview para inserir os dados do cliente

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="clientes" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Loja %>"
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Loja.ProviderName %>"
        EnableCaching="true"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [sexo] FROM Cliente ORDER BY Id" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Cliente] ([sexo]) VALUES (@sexo)" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Cliente] SET [sexo] = @sexo WHERE [Id] = @Id" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Doente] WHERE [Id] = @Id">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="sexo" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="sexo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:ListView ID="listaClientes" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id"
        DataSourceID="clientes">
        <ItemTemplate>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>

        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>

                    Sexo:
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSexo" runat="server"
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblSexo_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text ="Masculino" Value="1" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text ="Feminino" Value="2" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList><br />
        </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

A minha duvida é como irei guardar no no atributo (sexo da BD) o que o utilizador selecionar na RadioButtonList?

Pensei em utilizar:

```
string = "INSERT INTO [Doente] (sexo) VALUES (@sexo)";
command.Parameters.Add("@sexo", rblSexo.SelectedItem.Value);
```

no Inserted Event do sqlDataSource, o que acham?

Comment: Deste modo funciona?

Comment: Vejo alguns pontos estranhos na sua implementação. 1 - Porque você usa NVarchar? Tem necessidade de guardar dados em Unicode? O sexo é o que? Número? ou a inicial? M/F? Entendo que isso não seja diretamente relevante com a sua pergunta mas se você estiver usando só M/F poderia usar um char.

Comment: Resolvido? Caso positivo dê aceite nas repostas pois sua pergunta ainda está como aberta :-(

Answer (score 1):

Como seu campo espera um `nvarchar`, suponho que você queira passa o o texto "Masculino" ou "Feminino", se for isso o correto seria você passa dessa forma.

```
protected void rblSexo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = myConnString;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Doente] (sexo) VALUES (@sexo)";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@sexo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = rblSexo.SelectedItem.Text;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException sqle)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Só um detalhe, se você estive fazendo isso no evento do `OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblSexo_SelectedIndexChanged`, isso faz com que seja inserido uma linha na tabela cada vez que o usuário mudar o `sexo`, outra o `OnSelectedIndexChanged` só ira funcionar se vc declará o  `AutoPostBack="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que o radio button é um valor 1 ou 2, você pode mudar o tipo do parâmetro para Int32 
e o seu insert ficaria:

```
string = "INSERT INTO [Doente] (sexo) VALUES (@sexo)";
command.Parameters.Add("@sexo", Convert.ToInt32(rblSexo.SelectedItem.Value));
```

Comment: `Base de dados: o atributo sexo é um nvarchar`